# Initialising requirejs app in both optimised and non-optimised build

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, r.js

I'm confused about my r.js optimised script. I imagine the answer to my question is in the documentation but I think I'm going doc-blind from staring at it too long.

My application has a directory structure like this

```
-index.htm
-js/app.js
-js/init.js
-js/appname/*.js
```

When in non-optimised mode index.htm contains the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require-2.1.11.js"></script>
```

and everything works fine. My abridged `js/app.js` script looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({

baseUrl: 'js',

paths: {
    ...
}

});

require(['init']);
```

When I build the optimised script I specify `js/app.js` as the `mainConfigFile` and everything builds as expected. However when I update my script tag's `data-main` attribute to the build product my application doesn't initialise.

If I manually execute `require(['init'])` in the console it starts up as expected. Because r.js is using `js/app.js` as its config file that doesn't get included in the optimised script, which means my `require(['init'])` also doesn't get included.

I thought I could fix this by moving `require(['init'])` to the end of `js/init.js` and this does fix the optimised build (it initialised as expected), but now that the call isn't in `js/app.js` the non-optimised version never initialises. If I include the call in both files I get an error.

How can I ensure my first module is required after either the optimised or non-optimised file(s) are loaded? I don't understand how I'm supposed to make that first call after my first module's dependencies have fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because r.js is using js/app.js as its config file that doesn't get included in the optimised script

Well, then modify the build config you pass to `r.js` so that `js/app.js` *is included* in the final optimized bundle. There's nothing that forbids you from including the file you point to with `mainConfigFile` in the final bundle.

Comment: Aha excellent! For some reason I thought the r.js config's `compile.options.name` had to reference a module defined with the `define()` wrapper, which the app script isn't